# Conditionally display Row Detail

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, rowdetailstemplate

What if the row has no details?
I am using WPF `DataGrid` for displaying data with a row details templete.
I do not want row details if the user has no address details. I just want row details for only those users that have address details.

```
<DataGrid  Name="dgSimple" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="60" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirrstName}" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="60" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="60" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="60" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Birthday" Binding="{Binding Birthday}" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="60" Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderThickness="0" Background="BlanchedAlmond" Padding="10">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="Address: " VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <TextBlock FontSize="16" Foreground="MidnightBlue" Text="{Binding Address}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

```
public GridEX_5()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    List<User> users = new List<User>();
    users.Add(new User() { Address = "ABC", Id = 1, FirrstName = "John Doe", LastName = "John Doe", Name = "John Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1971, 7, 23) });
    users.Add(new User() { Address = "ABC", Id = 2, FirrstName = "John Doe", LastName = "John Doe", Name = "Jane Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1974, 1, 17) });
    users.Add(new User() { Address = "ABC", Id = 3, FirrstName = "John Doe", LastName = "John Doe", Name = "Sammy Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1991, 9, 2) });
    users.Add(new User() { Address = "ABC", Id = 1, FirrstName = "John Doe", LastName = "John Doe", Name = "John Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1971, 7, 23) });
    users.Add(new User() { Address = "ABC", Id = 2, FirrstName = "John Doe", LastName = "John Doe", Name = "Jane Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1974, 1, 17) });
    users.Add(new User() { Address = "ABC", Id = 3, FirrstName = "John Doe", LastName = "John Doe", Name = "Sammy Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1991, 9, 2) });
    users.Add(new User() { Address = "ABC", Id = 1, FirrstName = "John Doe", LastName = "John Doe", Name = "John Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1971, 7, 23) });
    users.Add(new User() { Address = "ABC", Id = 2, FirrstName = "John Doe", LastName = "John Doe", Name = "Jane Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1974, 1, 17) });
    users.Add(new User() { Address = "ABC", Id = 3, FirrstName = "John Doe", LastName = "John Doe", Name = "Sammy Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1991, 9, 2) });
    users.Add(new User() { Address = "ABC", Id = 1, FirrstName = "John Doe", LastName = "John Doe", Name = "John Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1971, 7, 23) });
    users.Add(new User() { Address = "ABC", Id = 2, FirrstName = "John Doe", LastName = "John Doe", Name = "Jane Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1974, 1, 17) });
    users.Add(new User() { Address = "ABC", Id = 3, FirrstName = "John Doe", LastName = "John Doe", Name = "Sammy Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1991, 9, 2) });
    users.Add(new User() { Address = "ABC", Id = 1, FirrstName = "John Doe", LastName = "John Doe", Name = "John Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1971, 7, 23) });
    users.Add(new User() { Address = "ABC", Id = 2, FirrstName = "John Doe", LastName = "John Doe", Name = "Jane Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1974, 1, 17) });
    users.Add(new User() { Id = 3, FirrstName = "John Doe", LastName = "John Doe", Name = "Sammy Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1991, 9, 2) });
    users.Add(new User() { Id = 1, FirrstName = "John Doe", LastName = "John Doe", Name = "John Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1971, 7, 23) });
    users.Add(new User() { Id = 2, FirrstName = "John Doe", LastName = "John Doe", Name = "Jane Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1974, 1, 17) });
    users.Add(new User() { Id = 3, FirrstName = "John Doe", LastName = "John Doe", Name = "Sammy Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1991, 9, 2) });

    dgSimple.ItemsSource = users;
}
```

[image: Application with a DataGrid displaying users and a selected row that shows its row details (the address of the user).]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an `ItemContainerStyle` with a `DataTrigger` that checks ifthe `Address` property is `null` and sets the [`DetailsVisibility`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridrow.detailsvisibility?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) property of the row to `Collapsed` in order to hide it.

```
<DataGrid  Name="dgSimple" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Address}" Value="{x:Null}">
               <Setter Property="DetailsVisibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
   <!-- ...other markup. -->
</DataGrid>
```

If the row details template grows and you want to hide only specific parts, you could also try to hide them using triggers in the `DataTemplate`. However, if you hide all elements like in this example, the border of the container will still be visible (a bold line on selection).

```
<DataTemplate>
   <Border x:Name="RowDetailsContainer"  BorderThickness="0" Background="BlanchedAlmond" Padding="10">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="Address: " VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBlock FontSize="16" Foreground="MidnightBlue" Text="{Binding Address}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
         </StackPanel>
      </StackPanel>
   </Border>
   <DataTemplate.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Address}" Value="{x:Null}">
         <Setter TargetName="RowDetailsContainer" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
      </DataTrigger>
   </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```